# How can I send e-mail from linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, email

I have tried this, but it is not working:

```
mail -s 'Teszt' myaddress@gmail.com < notes.txt
```

Comment: Have you installed `sendmail`?

Comment: First check, if sendmail is installed. Than, replace the single quotes(') with double quotes(")

Comment: It is also possible with telnet, in addition to your method stated: http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet

Comment: I would suggest you explain "not working", when you do I'll remove my -1. Does the email send, does it error.... More details please.

Comment: Dave Rook: There is no error message, but I have not got the e-mails.

Answer (score 2):

Many email providers will not accept traffic from an IP that's from a residental ISP.  Furthermore, many ISPs block outgoing SMTP traffic.  So you usually will have many problems trying to directly send email via SMTP from your home PC.

You probably need to install `exim4` or other MTA, and configure it to use an external email as a "smarthost."  Outgoing email will appear to come from this email address.  On Debian this is fairly easy with an `apt-get install exim4` and then answer the configuration questions.

If you are running on Debian or Ubuntu, you might have this installed already.  Run `dpkg-reconfigure exim4` from a root terminal to re-run the setup questions.

After you do that the above command will likely begin to work.